# Estilos imprimir datos JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, color, estilos, style

Necesito un programa que:

- Con 3 inputs pregunte nombre, apellidos y nota.
- Dos botones "añadir" y "mostrar".
- Al hacer click en "añadir" los datos se añadirán a un array vacío previamente creado y se borrarán los inputs.
- Al hacer click en "mostrar" aparecerá la lista de los alumnos, uno por línea.
- Se deben mostrar de forma distinta (color, negrita, cursiva, etc.) las notas superiores/iguales e inferiores a 5.

**No sé cómo se debe escribir la fórmula mostrar() ya que no me aparece el listado de forma distinta según si la nota es superior, igual o inferior a 5.**

Mi código ahora mismo es:

```
<body>

    <form name="cuarto" method="post">
        <label for="nombre">Escribe el nombre:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br>

        <label for="apellidos">Escribe los apellidos:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos"><br>

        <label number="nota">Escribe la nota (0 - 10):</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="nota" name="nota" min="0" max="10" step=".01"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="añadir()">AÑADIR</button>

        <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">MOSTRAR</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>
    </form>

    <script>
        var arraydatos = [];

        function añadir(){
            let n = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            let a = document.getElementById('apellidos').value;
            let no = document.getElementById('nota').value;
            arraydatos=arraydatos.concat(n+" "+a+" "+no);
            document.getElementById('nombre').value = "";
            document.getElementById('apellidos').value = "";
            document.getElementById('nota').value = "";
        }

        function mostrar(){
        if (document.getElementById('nota').value<5) {
            document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
              document.getElementById("demo").style.fontStyle = "normal";
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += arraydatos;
        } else if (document.getElementById('nota').value>=5){
            document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "green";
            document.getElementById("demo").style.fontStyle = "italic";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += arraydatos;
        } 
        }

    </script>


</body>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el ámbito de las variables que creas en la función añadir, por cierto cámbiale el nombre para que no te de problemas a uno que no incluya la letra ñ, son exclusivas para esa función solamente, es decir, en la función mostrar no ves los valores de esas variables y debes crearlas de nuevo o pasarlas de la función añadir a la función mostrar por parámetros...como más te guste. Estoy trabajando en ello y te paso la solución a tu problema. Be patient my friend. Aquí esta la version 1.0, mas mejoras dentro de otro rato:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Challenge: Catwalk</title>
<style>
    #cat {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form name="cuarto" method="post">
    <label for="nombre">Escribe el nombre:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br>

    <label for="apellidos">Escribe los apellidos:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos"><br>

    <label number="nota">Escribe la nota (0 - 10):</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="nota" name="nota" min="0" max="10" step=".01"><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="agregar()">AÑADIR</button>

    <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">MOSTRAR</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</form>

<script>
    var arraydatos = [];
    let alumno;

    function agregar() {
        alumno = new Object();
        let nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
        let apellidos = document.getElementById('apellidos').value;
        let nota = document.getElementById('nota').value;
        alumno.nombre = nombre;
        alumno.apellidos = apellidos;
        alumno.nota = nota;
        arraydatos.push(alumno);
        document.getElementById('nombre').value = "";
        document.getElementById('apellidos').value = "";
        document.getElementById('nota').value = "";
    }

    function mostrar() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arraydatos.length; i++) {
            let nota = arraydatos[i].nota;
            let nombre = arraydatos[i].nombre;
            let apellidos = arraydatos[i].apellidos;

            let alumno = apellidos + ", " + nombre + " ha obtenido una nota de " + nota;
            if (nota < 5) {
                document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("demo").style.fontStyle = "normal";
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += `<span style="color:red">` + alumno + "</span><br/>";
            } else if (nota >= 5) {
                document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "green";
                document.getElementById("demo").style.fontStyle = "italic";
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += `<span style="color:green">` + alumno + "</span><br/>";
            }
        }

    }

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Esto es una primera version con algunos fallos....pero ya se le va viendo la punta....Si imprimes un alumno solamente sale bien, si imprimes mas no por que no he tenido en cuenta aun el array entero. Seguimos para bingo.

Creo que ya está la version definitiva...echadle un ojo y me comentais si funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Pues mira, no sé si será porque copiaste mal el enunciado o porque el ejercicio esté mal de por si, pero no hay por donde tomarlo, y te explico el porqué:

1. Todos esos datos no se pueden meter en un array, ni simple ni asociativo ni nada. Esto es debido a que normalmente los array contienen un tipo de datos, por ejemplo un array de "nombres":

   const nombres = ["samantha","rigoberto","anastasia"];

Con esto podrias sacar datos como "nombres de estas personas", "cantidad de nombres"...etc.
Para lo que tú quieres hacer es más complejo: sería crear una función que añadiese esos datos en un array nuevo cada vez tipo "persona1", "persona2"...o incluso si me apuras meter los distintos datos en 3 array distintos "nombres", "apellidos", "notas"; eso si, todos ordenados respectivamente.

2. Teniendo en cuenta lo de más arriba, no se puede realizar lo de "si la nota es mayor de 5, que el párrafo esté en verde", ya que ¿cómo tomas el valor de esa array si está todo pegado? No tiene sentido.

Bueno, y aparte de lo que he mostrado, puntualizar que hay errores de "novato" que tienes por allí como el no ahorrar código, declaras varias veces las mismas cosas o el no añadir la etiqueta  (que a lo mejor te lo has ahorrado, eso no lo sé).

Espero haberte ayudado en algo, deberías de reformular el problema como dije anteriormente, así te podríamos ayudar de forma más eficiente. Un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Unicamente te voy a resaltar los errores que estas cometiendo en código ya que es claro que apenas estas aprendiendo a programar.

Tu código no funciona porque :

```
var arraydatos = [];
```

En realidad no tiene un arreglo definido lo correcto es :

```
var arraydatos = [0];
```

agregas espacios y registro en el haciendo :

```
arraydatos.push(n + " " + a + " " , no);
```

Esta sentencia también la escribiste mal la original es :

```
arraydatos=arraydatos.concat(n+" "+a+" "+no);
```

al definir una variable con var dejas a js que interprete el tipo de dato y al concatenar lo se convierte en string esto causando que no entres a tu ciclo if por eso la , 
mas adelante:

```
document.getElementById('nota').value = "";
```

aqui también estas dándole a entender a js que "no" es un strign asi que ponle un default = 0

```
document.getElementById('nota').valu = 0;
```

también debes de cambiar la función en como imprimes los registros.

Haciendo estas correcciones tu ejercicio funcionara aunque no es lo mejor pero sigue estudiando y practicando y eventualmente mejoraras tus desarrollos.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he obtenido el resultado que quería con el siguiente código:

```
<body>

    <form name="cuarto" method="post">
        <label for="nombre">Escribe el nombre:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br>

        <label for="apellidos">Escribe los apellidos:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos"><br>

        <label number="nota">Escribe la nota (0 - 10):</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="nota" name="nota" min="0" max="10" step=".01"><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="añadir()">AÑADIR</button>

        <button type="button" onclick="mostrar()">MOSTRAR</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p id="demo2"></p>
    </form>

    <script>
        var alumno ={
                nombre: "",
                apellidos: "",
                nota:10,
        };

        function añadir(){
            alumno.nombre=document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            alumno.apellidos=document.getElementById('apellidos').value;
            alumno.nota=parseFloat(document.getElementById('nota').value);
            document.getElementById('nombre').value = "";
            document.getElementById('apellidos').value = "";
            document.getElementById('nota').value = "";
        }

        function mostrar(){
        var text = alumno.nombre+" "+alumno.apellidos+" "+alumno.nota;
        if (alumno.nota<5) {
            document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("demo").style.fontStyle = "normal";
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text + "<br/>";
        } else if (alumno.nota>=5){
             document.getElementById("demo2").style.color = "green";
            document.getElementById("demo2").style.fontStyle = "italic";
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += text + "<br/>";
        } 
        }

    </script>


</body>
```

Muchas gracias a tod@s!!